# TClientDataset Widestring field doubles in size after reading NVARCHAR from database

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm converting one of our Delphi 7 projects to Delphi X3 because we want to support Unicode. We're using MS SQL Server 2008/R2 as our database server. After changing some database fields from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR (and the fields in the accompanying ClientDatasets to ftWideString), random crashes started to occur. While debugging I noticed some unexpected behaviour by the TClientDataset/DbExpress:

For a NVARCHAR(10) databasecolumn I manually create a TWideStringField in a clientdataset and set the 'Size' property to 10. The 'DataSize' property of the field tells me 22 bytes are needed, which is expected since TWideStringField's encoding is UTF-16, so it needs two bytes per character and some space for storing the length. Now when I call 'CreateDataset' on the ClientDataset and write the dataset to XML (using .SaveToFile), in the XML file the field is defined as

`<FIELD WIDTH="20" fieldtype="string.uni" attrname="TEST"/>`

which looks ok to me.

Now, instead of calling .CreateDataset I call .Open on the TClientDataset so that it gets its data through the linked components ->TDatasetProvider->TSQLDataset (.CommandText = a simple select * from table)->TSQLConnection. When I inspect the properties of the field in my watch list, Size is still 10, Datasize is still 22. After saving to XML file however, the field is defined as

`<FIELD WIDTH="40" fieldtype="string.uni" attrname="TEST"/>`

..the width has doubled?

Finally, if I call .Open on the TClientDataset without creating any fielddefinitions in advance at all, the Size of the field will afterwards be **20(incorrect !)** and Datasize 42. After saving to XML, the field is still defined as

`<FIELD WIDTH="40" fieldtype="string.uni" attrname="TEST"/>`

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible you forgot to Adjust the fields in DatasetProvider.Dataset?

Comment: DatasetProvider.Dataset points to a TSQLDataset and I don't have any fields/fielddefinitions at all in this TSQLDataset.

Comment: For testing I changed the TSQLDataset's CommandMode from ctQuery into ctTable and made the designer retrieve the fielddefinitions which resulted in the same wrong result: a TWideStringField of size 20.

Comment: 1)Have you cleaned all your DCU's and made sure to rebuild from scratch? 2) Are you using components that you plopped down from the component palette? Just a hunch, but if so, maybe you need to delete them, put on new ones and again, delete all output and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 went completely out of support almost 5 years ago. You really should not be doing new development against an unsupported version. You need to get an upgrade path sorted out and get on a supported version.

Answer (score 0):

Check the fieldtype and it's size at the SQLCommand component (which is before DatasetProvider).

Size doubling may be a result of two implicit "conversions": first - server provides NVarchar data which is stored into ansi-string field (and every byte becomes a separate character), second - it is stored into clientdataset's field of type Widestring and each character becomes 2 bytes (size doubles).

Note that in prior versions of Delphi string field size mismatch between ClientDataset's field and corresponding Query/Command field did not result in an exception but starting from one of XE*'s it offten results in AV. So you have to check carefully string field sizes during migration.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like because of the column datatype being changed, it has created unexpected issues for you. My suggestion is to 
1. back up the table,multiple ways to doing this,pick your poison figuratively speaking 
2. delete the table, 
3. recreate the table, 
4. import the data from the old table to the newly created table. See if that helps.

Sql tables DO NOT like it when column datatypes get changed, and unexpected issues may arise from doing just that. So try that, and worst case scenario, you have wasted maybe ten minutes of your time trying a possible solution.